# Physymb not working with fontspec unless a different font is loaded not via fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, incompatibility, latin-modern

I am having trouble using the `physymb` and `fontspec` packages together. When I compile using `PDFLaTeX`, everything works, even with the `lmodern` package. However, when I compile with `XeLaTeX`, it does not work if I've loaded `fontspec` (even if I don't use it), but it does work if I later load the package `mathpazo` (which I don't really want to use, but found via debugging). My question is, where are these errors coming from and is there a workaround? Will loading only certain fonts work?

The document I'm using to test is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    \usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
    %\usepackage{mathpazo} % If you commento ut this line you get many errors.
\else
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi

\usepackage{physymb}

\begin{document}
    This is sample text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is with the `accents` package. You should report the issue to the package author; meanwhile, the `no-math` option for `fontspec` should allow compiling the document.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that within a few hours. You should put that in an answer so I can accept it if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `accents` package; I guess that some cooperation between `accents` and `fontspec` is in order, so the best is to contact both package maintainers.

A workaround is to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option: this doesn't produce the error, but may have other consequences.

Another one is to patch something before the damage is done:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{physymb}

\let\acute\relax
\let\grave\relax
\let\ddot\relax
\let\tilde\relax
\let\bar\relax
\let\breve\relax
\let\check\relax
\let\hat\relax
\let\dot\relax
\let\mathring\relax

\ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
    \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi


\begin{document}

This is sample text.

\end{document}
```

In my small experiments, it seems that the accents work well, using the `accents` definition, albeit slighly modified. This might be the best way to temporarily solve the incompatibility.

Comment: I think for this I will go for the `no-math` option, but I'll keep the rest in mind if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can fool the package that `accents` is already loaded

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@accents.sty}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{physymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    This is sample text.
\end{document}
```

You should load LaTeX related font packages *always* before fontspec!

Comment: Why should you *always* load font packages before fontspec? Do the font packages otherwise break things in fontspec subtly, and fontspec knows how to handle it if it's loaded later, or is there a different reason? Even if it's that, can you expand on that point?

Comment: yes, they can break settings from `fontspec`